# Should quotes be in pre-formatted blocks?

Tags: discusión, faq, formato

I noticed a user has recently been mass-editing dozens of posts to change all quotes in quotation marks to use Markdown's `pre-formatted text` formatting. My understanding was that pre-formatted blocks like this are supposed to be used for code or similar technical fragments, not for quotes in natural language. I personally think that this formatting looks bad on a language site and goes against orthography norms in both English and Spanish.

How should `pre-formatted text` be used on this site?

Comment: I agree that pre-formatted text should rarely (if ever) be used on a site like this. Block quoting can make sense, but not with pre-formatted text.

Comment: So is this the intended way to do things in this site? Just to confirm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree. Pre-formatted text should be used for code or otherwise technical stuff. Regular text being quoted from sources should be displayed in quotation marks or by using the quote feature if too long, like this:

> Reviewing what you have learned and learning anew, you are fit to be a teacher.

My two cents.